How to use custom (created with Ukulele) keyboard layout in the FileVault password screen on macOS 14.7
I created a custom keyboard layout using Ukulele, and currently have it installed as .bundle file in /Library/Keyboard Layouts (Not using a .bundle seems to break keyboard shortcuts in some apps, at least Premiere Pro). I set it as default in system settings and it works for use while in OS and in the normal lock screen (though it's not selectable in the list and it shows that U.S. is selected, my keyboard layout is selected and works). However, it's not available for choice nor selected in the FileVault unlocking screen, and I am not sure how to change that. I'm using macOS 14.7

You aren’t running macOS at the FileVault unlock screen, so this may be challenging to inject configuration and software into the pre-boot firmware.

You can also ask in the Ukelele group:   https://groups.google.com/g/ukelele-users?pli=1
